# Django Rest Framework indirect nested writing

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer with a nested many-to-many field and the parent serializer has a create() override:

```
tags = TagSerialiser(many=True)
```

I want to have the m2m read-only, but the POST will contain data for it. In this case, I want to lookup pre-existing tags based on their string and link those, otherwise create a new tag (normalizing on tag string) along with other checks and model creations.

When setting the serializer field for the relation to read-only, the data isn't passed to created even though it is POSTed.

Setting it to read/write causes validation errors as the create() method is *later* than the creation of the nested relationship. In my case, I get exceptions for unique constraints.

Is there a way to handle writing of nested relationships in my create() method? I want to create the model here or link existing models. Using a PK/URL relationship and having DRF resolve it isn't an option.

(Django Rest Framework 3.0.2, Django 1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set it to `readonly`  and then get the data using `POST` not validated_data

```
def create(self,validated_data):
    request = self.context['request']
    _tags = request.POST.get('tags',None)
    # then create your tags instances
    tags = Tag.objects.bulk_create(_tags)
    # and then create your main object.
```